# Set scrollbar thickness

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, scrollbar

Is there a way to adjust the thickness of the scrollbar within a `JScrollPane`? the default is kind of clunky.

Comment: I've added a more complete solution below, that works for the default look and feel (Metal).  I know this is an old question, but I came across it when I was trying to figure this out, so thought I'd come back and share.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A quick but also dirty solution is to set the width/height explicitely to e.g. 10 pixels via

```
jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 0));
jScrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 10));
```

Other way would be to provide a proper `ScrollBarUI`.

Comment: Thanks! And how do I set the size of the scrollbar up/down buttons?

Comment: This does weird things to the direction buttons. See my answer below for a alternate solution.

Answer (score 5):

The following applies to the default LNF (Metal).

If you just want to set a specific size, then you can put this code before you create the JScrollPane (replace 40 with whatever size you prefer)...

```
UIManager.put("ScrollBar.width", 40);
```

If you want to scale the scrollbar based on the default size then something like this (before you create the JScrollPane)...

```
UIManager.put("ScrollBar.width", (int) ((int) UIManager.get("ScrollBar.width") * 2.5));
```

If you want to change it *after* creating the JScrollPane things are a bit more complex, but not too bad...

```
int scrollbarSize = <some dynamic value>;
UIManager.put("ScrollBar.width", scrollbarSize);
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBar(scrollPane.createVerticalScrollBar());
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBar(scrollPane.createHorizontalScrollBar());
```

I hope that helps someone.

Comment: This only works if you DON'T have the Nimbus LaF. If you have it then the first way has no effect and the second way errors because `UIManager.get("ScrollBar.width") == null`

Answer (score 2):

```
int verticalScrollBarWidthCoefficient = 3;

scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(
        (int) scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getPreferredSize()
                .getWidth() * verticalScrollBarWidthCoefficient,
        (int) scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getPreferredSize().getHeight()
));
```

Answer (score -4):

simplest way for me was to edit the `jquery.jscrollpane.css` file directly. changing the width of `.jspVerticalBar`. :)