# How to edit the Scroll Bar

Tags: java, swing, custom-component, jscrollbar

I have a JTable in a JScrollPane but I'd like to change the look of the ScrollBar to something a bit better looking; a 'custom design'. Maybe put an image that a user can drag instead of the default thick blue bar. Is this even possible?

The main thing I'd like to do is change the thickness of the bar. My application uses a small window and the ScrollBar looks too thick.

Any help will be much appreciated.

**Edit:**
*Thanks for the responses so far. I just found this; answers my answer, in part: [java scrollbar thickness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371547/java-scrollbar-thickness)*

Comment: Start by having a look at [How to set the look and feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html), maybe using something else will meet you needs better. Failing that take a look at [Synth Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I cannot provide a sample at the current moment, but you should definitely look into [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicScrollBarUI.html)

The `BasicScrollBarUI` class allows you to modify different features of a typical `JScrollBar`, such as various different colors, sizes, and shadow effects. This should be what you are looking for. Basically the idea is that you are supposed to override the `installDefaults` method and just modify the protected fields to your liking.

But, if you want to get fancy, I would highly suggest looking into [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/) due to the amount of customizability it supports, one being CSS styling (which should be very helpful to you).